# Disable Cisco Webex Meetings auto-start

Tags: autostart, webex

I have been using Cisco Webex Meetings for past three years, but I am using it so rarely that from time to time I simply uninstall its client and install it again whenever it is required (directly from "Join the Meeting" screen in my web browser after clicking an invitation link).

Last time it was installed (about a week ago) it bring me a new version that has auto-start feature enabled by default. Now, each time I start my computer I see this dully and annoying screen:

[image]

How can I turn off the whole auto-start idea for Cisco Webex Meetings?

There is no appropriate option in the settings section, because there is no setting at all. When you click the gear icon you can only read some stuff and send support request.

The only option I am left with is to close this program manually, each time Windows starts. But that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hits from Cisco on this did not work; the interface must have changed--can't find any preferences as they indicate.

The following link worked for me on MacOS:

https://macpaw.com/how-to/remove-startup-items-in-osx

Go to apple menu -> System Preferences then Users & Groups, pick your user then go to the Login Items tab, highlight the app and remove with the - button

The following link should work on Windows 10:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2944-add-delete-enable-disable-startup-items-windows-10-a.html

right-click in the taskbar, select "Task Manager", select the "Startup" tab; look for your application and click on "Enable" to disable it.

There may be other options available (see the linked web page).

Comment: I did not notice question was for Windows!

Comment: This works for removing it once on MacOS, however it returns to the login items after every launch.

Comment: Crappiest usability experience ever. Pops up randomly, cannot right click -> quit. Pure crapware.

Comment: Task Manager did the trick for me on Windows. I used Webex as a guest only once. - Just see the logon screen and cannot click the cog icon to access the settings, because I don't have a proper Webex account. **It is impossible to enter settings from logon screen.**

Comment: I cannot understand why it is *Disabled* in my Task Manager startup list but still Webex pops up at Windows 10 start. Removing the registry entries did the trick, instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Task Manager, I did not see an app listing in the Startup tab for this, but I did see a vague "Program" listing with no information.  I disabled that entry and it did not start up upon reboot.

[image]

Comment: A downvote without a reason is not very helpful to visitors.  Better to explain why you think this is not useful/helpful information.

Comment: Seems that your answer is to wide. Try to look around for other questions and answers to see what format is preferred here. For me personally your answer is hard to understand -- where did you see this (Start Menu)? What "Program" did you see? How did you disable it (removing Start Menu shortcut)? Etc.

Comment: I'd imagine those who downvoted did so because, while it may be useful/helpful information, it's not an answer per se; it belongs in a comment.

Comment: @trejder I updated my answer, hopefully that is more in line with convention?

Comment: @blackworx since my answer specifically resolves OPs initial comment, how is it not an answer?  Always trying to learn here, so thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 (no 'Startup' tab in Task Manager as described in accepted W10 solution):

Remove the registry entry in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` which points to `ptoneclk.exe`

Answer (score 1):

The ["IT Administrator Guide for Mass Deployment of the CiscoWebex WBS39.10 and Later.pdf"](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/collaboration/webex_centers/esp/webex_b_it-administrator-guide-mass-deployment-desktop-app.pdf) states to install with `/AUTOOC=0`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice from the qustion itself and uninstalled webex.

*(Not trying to duplicate information but I think it bears repeating in case people breeze past the question.)*