# Cisco Webex Application continuously returns to Login Items

Tags: macos, webex

Every time you launch the Cisco WebEx Application it will install itself, unprompted to the user Login Items, so that it will launch upon every restart.

This isn't a duplicate of this question:

[Disable Cisco Webex Meetings auto-start](https://superuser.com/questions/1397828/disable-cisco-webex-meetings-auto-start)

As this is Mac specific, and is referring more to its pervasive re-installation of itself into the Login Items.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to disable this functionality. According to "Cisco Cloud Support" this is their official stance:

> Thank you for your time and patience. I have investigated it and I would like to inform you that as the WebEx Meetings Desktop application requires credentials it will show the Cisco WebEx Application under Login Items under Users & Groups and cannot be removed from the Login items. It is not an issue with the WebEx.
>
> We request you to contact Mac technical support once regarding this.

Of course, this is nonsense. In an earlier response, I received this:

> Thank you for performing the suggested steps. I would like to inform you that it is a feature in Mac and as the WebEx Meetings Desktop application requires credentials it will show the Cisco WebEx Application under Login Items under Users & Groups. It is not an issue with WebEx.  Also I don’t believe that it can be removed from the login items.
>
> However, we request you to contact Mac technical support once regarding this issue.

Of course you can manually remove it from Login Items after each time you launch the application, but this is annoyingly frustrating. Removing it from Login Items does not affect the functionality in any way, it simply prevents it from launching upon login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They recently added the checkbox to the application preferences to `Start Cisco Webex Meetings when my computer starts` and unchecking that box properly removes the application from Login Items.

[image: Cisco Webex Meetings -> Preferences Window]